# how to display the datatable column data as hyperlink in data grid view using C#

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

sir am new to asp.net please any one help me

sir i have one column as 3-10-2011 1:00:00 3-10-2011 1:15:00 3-10-2011 1:30:00.................in datatable and i want to display in grid column as follows

```
       1:00
       1:15
       1:30
       1:45
       2:00

       .
      .........
```

these are display like hyper links and when user click on any one then a pop window should be open how can i achieve it please help me please tell me in detail please

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`HyperLinkColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkcolumn.aspx) control and [`DataTextFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkcolumn.datatextformatstring.aspx) property.  For opening a popup window you will need JavaScript [`window.open`](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) method in your `NavigateUrl` setting.

Comment: how to fromat the column as above mentioned

Comment: See the "t" format string in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx, or the custom date time format strings here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx.  And try **Google** next time.  Please at least show some effort yourself if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="javascript:void(window.open('popup.aspx', 'test', 'width=800, height=600'));"><%#Eval("TimeColumn")%></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```